# Using the R package " termstrc "

Tags: fixed-income, r, statistical-finance, bond-yields

I am attempting to use the function `estim_nss` from the `termstrc` package in R. However, I am experiencing the following error:

> Error in uniroot(pvcashflows, searchint, tol = tol, maxiter = 3000) : 
>   f() values at end points not of opposite sign

I read the manual and I have checked that I have specified my data input correctly, I truely do not know what the problem is.

The mannual says this error may arise due to wrongly specified start parameters or data issues, I have not specified any start parameters and i have checked my data a number of times, comparing it to the example, the format looks the same.

The line that i am runung is:

```
ns_res <- estim_nss(mybonds, "SA_GOV_BONDS1", method = "ns")
```

Can someone please shed some light on how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Try specifically calling on your data by an actual column, so for example, mybonds$Column1 etc and maybe that will help.

Comment: I have the same question. Have you solved it?